# Rank by created date and company name

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have table Company. I need to display the TOP 6 recently created.
Exemple of data:

[image]

Expected results

[image]

What I tried :

```
Rank = 
VAR d = Companies[CreatedDate].[Date] 
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        RANK.EQ ( d, Companies[CreatedDate], DESC)

    )
```

the calculated column returned wrong values:

[image]

I need to order by creatd date, and when it's the same date, I need to order by Company Namr

How to correct it!,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ranking based on created date and company name try the following steps, and if it helps accept it is as answer.

1. Create a calculated column for ranking the company name.

   ```
   Company Sort = RANKX(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[Company Name], , ASC)
   ```
2. Create another calculated column for ranking using following DAX

   ```
    Ranking on Date and Company Name = 
    VAR X = MAX('Table'[Company Sort])

    var res = 
             RANKX(
             ALL('Table),
            'Table'[Created Date] * X + 'Table'[Company Sort]
          )

   RETURN res
   ```
3. Sort by using the column `Ranking on Date and Company Name'.

[image: Ranking]

4. If you want to create a visual, then just add the column `Ranking on Date and Company Name' in the filter pane and select the Top N filter accordingly.

[image: Final Output]